# Ordering products using custom field and pagination

Tags: elementquery

I have element query that orders products by custom field which is numeric. Default value of this field is "1".

```
{% set products = products.relatedTo(category).orderBy('productOrderInCategory').inReverse() %}
```

All is fine, when i do this

```
{% set productList = products.all() %}
```

When i use pagination, order of products with same "productOrderInCategory" field value randomly changes each time page loads.

```
{% paginate products.limit(32) as pageInfo, paginatedProducts %}
```

So, product with larger productOrderInCategory value will always be first, but multiple products with same productOrderInCategory value will be randomly shuffled each time page loads.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field you're ordering by is identical across multiple products, the order in which those are returned is undefined (i.e. determined by the database, essentially random). To achieve a consistent sort order, you need to specify a second field to sort by if the first one is the same. For example, you could just sort products with the same `productOrderInCategory` alphabetically by title:

```
{% set products = products.relatedTo(category)
                    .orderBy('productOrderInCategory, title DESC')
                    .inReverse() %}
```

The syntax for sorting by multiple fields is [documented here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder#order-by).

Comment: Thank you, that helped.